# Pyenv - How to use existing interpreter as a venv

Tags: installation, versions, pyenv

My global default is 2.x, I don't want to change that due to possible internal use by other applications that I may be unaware of.

I can install new versions using `pyenv install`, but what I would like to do is have a venv point to the existing 3.4 anaconda install.  Essentially the behavior I want to emulate is that the pyenv version listed as `system`  calls `python3.4` instead of `python`.  Obviously I could change the default system python path to accomplish that, but I'd rather do it from within pyenv.

The reason is mainly to make pyenv and sublime play nice, because as far as I can tell, you must explicitly set the interpreter path for sublime, which cannot take advantage of the dynamic interpreter selection you get using pyenv (e.g. sublime won't respect the global version set in pyenv).

Answer (score 0):

The version of the Python interpreter that's first in your `$PATH` when you initialise pyenv is the one it regards as “system”.  So you can redefine your `$PATH` to put Anaconda’s Python first before you `eval "$(pyenv init -)”`.

But that’s a very clunky way to get pyenv and Anaconda to cohabit.  Much better to get pyenv to install Anaconda (or Miniconda).  Recent versions of pyenv and the pyenv-virtualenv plugin make this work quite seamlessly.

As for Sublime, if it needs an explicit path to the interpreter, just give it one?  I don’t quite understand how pyenv is relevant to this…?